# Could not use TRUNCATEion statement

Tags: sql-server

I want to truncate the table using the complete name. i.e. DatabaseName.SchemaName.TableName using variables in SQL Server.

Consider the following example:

```
DECLARE @destDatabaseName VARCHAR(50); 
DECLARE @destSchemaName VARCHAR(50) ; 

SET @destDatabaseName = 'Database_Name' ;
SET @destSchemaName = 'Schema_Name' ;

TRUNCATE TABLE [@destDatabaseName].[@destSchemaName].[Application] ;
```

It is giving me the following error.

> Msg 2702, Level 16, State 2, Line 25 
>  Database '@destDatabaseName' does
>   not exist.

Comment: can you not go USE [@destDatabaseName] and then TRUNCATE TABLE [@destSchemaName].[Application]? I haven't tried.. but just asking

Comment: No DDL statement takes a variable. You have to use dynamic SQL if you want to do it dynamically.

Comment: You cannot refer to a database name with a variable in a TRUNCATE statement or in any other T-SQL statement. You'll need dynamic SQL if you want to use a variable database.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a variable to represent an object. For example, if you have the statement:

```
DECLARE @Var sysname = N'MyColumn';

SELECT @Var
FROM MyTable;
```

You wouldn't get a statement with the values from `MyColumn`, you'd get a dataset which repeats the literal string `N'MyColumn'`. You need to use Dynamic SQL to do this:

```
--SQL Server uses sysname (nvarchar(128)) for object names, so I've changed the datatype here
DECLARE @destDatabaseName sysname; 
DECLARE @destSchemaName sysname; 
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);

SET @destDatabaseName = N'Database_Name';
SET @destSchemaName = N'Schema_Name';

SET @SQL = N'USE ' + QUOTENAME(@destDatabaseName) + N';' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) + 
           N'TRUNCATE TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(@destSchemaName) + N'.[Application];';

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```